# Symfony 3 - delete rows on intermediate table manyToMany

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

My problem : I have an entity User and an entity Skill. A user can have multi skills, and a skill can have multi users, so i have a relation ManyToMany on this. The result is a third intermediate table called "Users_Skills" with columns user_id and skill_id.

I want to delete rows on this table, by example all rows where id_user = 5.

I don't know how to do this, because I have no entity for the table Users_Skills, and no repository. What is th best way to do this ?

Answer (score 1):

generally when working with Doctrine ORM, you should think in terms of Objects and not in terms of tables and rows.

```
$user = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:User')->find(5);
$skills = $user->getSkills();

foreach ($skills as $skill)
{
    $user->removeSkill($skill);
}

$em->flush();
```

Another option

```
$user = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:User')->find(5);
$skills = $user->getSkills();
$skills->clear();
$em->flush();
```

Also do read about [Owning Side and Inverse Side](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/unitofwork-associations.html)

Answer (score 0):

You just need to get your User entity with the id 5, to empty his list of skills, then persist and flush.

Example (in a controller):

```
$id = 5;
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$repository = $em->getRepository(User::class);
$user = $repository->find($id);
$user->setSkills([]);
$em->flush();
```